Why do many people like to use "normal distribution" instead of $\beta$ distribution when the theoretical range of data is finite?
Say we are approximating the distribution of the test score of a large group of students, while the theoretical minimum score is 0 and the maximum is 100. In this case, many people use the normal distribution instead of the $\beta$ distribution. To me this is confusing as for a normal distribution, there is a positive probability for a student to have a test score less than zero or greater than 100, while in reality this probability should be zero.
Why don't people use $\beta$ distribution instead of normal distribution in this case (and in many other cases in real life when the theoretical range of data is finite)?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect

"Approximating" is the key word in this post.

Almost no real-world data is actually normally distributed, and yet the normal distribution is often the best and most convenient approximate model.

There are many normal approximations available, success of which often depends on the rate of convergence of some asymptotic result.

Sometimes normal approximation is unreasonable, like with estimating prediction intervals of Poisson point processes with small rate parameters.

The grounds for closing this question make no sense. It is a fact, demonstrated in the question, that in one substantial respect the beta distribution fits better than the normal distribution. And to the extent that it seems to call for opinion, it is about the practices of statisticians well within their expertise as statisticians.

@MichaelHardy isn't the opinion issue the claim that many people use the normal distribution instead of the beta distribution

can you link/quote an example which you have seen

Beta and scaled-beta distributions exist on finite ranges, sure, but they can't take on just any shape (a lot of shapes, sure, but not all of them). Having values limited to $(0,1)$ does not mean that the distribution must be beta-distributed.

@Dave, I agree with you! Would Beta-distribution be at least more flexible than the normal distribution?

It's very simple: The Gaussian distribution is convenient and the most widely implemented assumption in statistical software. Everyone who has taken a freshman-level statistics course gets taught methods based on the Gaussian distribution. The most widely-used software in the life sciences allows for two options only: Gaussian and nonparametric, and its implementation of Gaussian presumed homoscedasticity.
It's the default and requires no understanding of modeling or statistics to use. You get a sacred p value, so nothing else matters. The software even puts the magic stars on your graphics for you.

I don't understand the downvote; I think this answer is pretty much on target.

Thanks for the answer! So for some real-life data of large number of values between 0 and 100, if we compute the mean and the standard deviation, and then build two different models: Gaussian and $\beta$, which one tends to be more accurate in modelling the real data?

typically this is done only for large enough sample averages where Law of large numbers and CLT is expected to ensure
a) approximate normality of the sample average
b) distribution of sample average stays far from boundary.
see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval where normal approximations are covered as well as using the beta distribution
the obvious advantage of using the normal distribution is for ease of computation. ( eg how to look at statistical significance of difference (of 2 probability estimates,...)

If you want to emphasize the word only, then you certainly shouldn't use quotation marks, since, when properly understood, those weaken the word. Quotation marks would mean people call it "only" but you are not the one who says it's only for large samples, etc.

This answers a different question than the one asked, which concerns "distribution of the test score."  Neither laws of large numbers nor the CLT have anything whatsoever to say about such distributions generally.

I believe the question was not as clear cut as you suggest - my claim was that "the people" using normal approximations were probably looking at the sample average of test scores (eg over class etc), otherwise those people would be using the beta distribution.

That's a clear re-interpretation of the question: but unless you can cite a specific part of the question that supports it (which I still cannot find), then your answer continues to look off-target.  Further, I see no way to square your interpretation with the concern about the fixed limits of 0 and 100: those would have little or nothing to do with the sample averages you are discussing.

"Say we are approximating the distribution of the test score of a large group of students", - OP seems interested in the group (rather than an individual, where size of group seems irrelevant). op is concerned that normal distribution cannot represent a finite range (0-100), whereas sample average of those scores may well lie  well within that range (eg +/- 2 standard deviations)

I will end my part of this conversation just by reiterating that there is no ambiguity in the phrase "distribution of ... a group [of data]," and that sample averages have essentially nothing to tell us about that.
